# Identifying the professor by tiny piece of burned photo

Tags: plot-explanation, money-heist

In Money Heist S2E1, the lady inspector's husband collects a piece of a photo burned by the professor.
How can the police determine the professor's identity on the basis of that tiny piece of burned photograph?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier Professor was burning old photos of his father in the furnace, as well as a **newspapers** clipping of how his father was shot dead in a bank robber and there could be connection to him. Also he had no idea how bad/good photos it could be, so Professor rather replaces it with fakes.
Police could for example search all possible newspapers and compare it with the piece of paper. With the right software they could do it really fast.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know *how* that is done. "*With the right software*" is still very vague and probably far from the truth.

Comment: @Joachim for photo for example https://tineye.com/ - you don't need same photo, just part of it is usually enough. But I believe piece of newspaper would be more helpful, since you can search for a text and there could be even his name.

Comment: Remember it is (they are) a *burned* piece(s) of paper. You'll probably need forensic methods and software -TinEye (the publicly accessible version at least) is not near the level of sophistication professional image recognition software has.

Comment: It was the part of the burnt newspaper clipping the inspector found that gave the clue. Image recognition was not required.